# What error code to return to jQuery $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

What HTTP error code do I need to return to a jQuery ajax that would work with setting a response method? Using jQuery 1.7.

For example, I have the following code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/report/template/save",
            data: formData,
            success: function() {

            },
            statusCode: {
                400: function() {
                  $('#template_form .ajax-msg').show();
                  $('#template_form .ajax-msg').html('<strong>Sorry, save failed.');
                }
            }
        });
request.fail(function(data) {
            $('#template_form .ajax-msg').show();
            $('#template_form .ajax-msg').html('<strong>Sorry, save failed.');
        });
```

I can indeed verify a 400 is being returned.

If the form doesn't validate server-side, I've tried returning both a status 500 and 400 with no luck. Instead what happens is that the code is halted and the `.ajax-msg` doesn't display anything. What is `$.ajax` expecting? Thanks!

Comment: I never knew there was statusCode in ajax request, what I always did was check in success if a return value from server is success or error and show content accordingly

Comment: Yea it's nifty for disambiguating erorrs if I can get it to work. would help to separate validation and server errors. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I think you have too many handlers registered. Remove the success and fail handlers and try using only the "statusCode" handler.

Comment: have you tested to see if the response is ending up in the success handler instead of the statusCode handler?

Comment: I removed all handlers except for statusCode, and still no dice. i wonder if there's a conflict somewhere. i'm going to set a breakpoint and see if it is indeed ending up in success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple conflicts present and thanks to the comments I was able to sort through it.

First, there were too many success handlers (and in my opinion the naming is a little ambiguous). I removed `statusCode` and replaced with `request.fail` and `request.always` which allowed me to do actions with each response anyways.

Second, the code wasn't actually halting but I mistakenly screwed up on a selector and `$('#template_form .ajax-msg')` was changed to `'$('.modal .ajax-msg')`.

I hope that helps future problems!